# Ajax in jQuery with ASP.NET return whole html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

this is my jquery...

```
$("#testAjax").on("click", function () {     
    //alert('asd');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Index.aspx/ajaxTest',
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      }
    });
});
```

and this is my behind the code

```
[WebMethod]
public string ajaxTest()
{
    var test = "hello";

    return test;
}
```

i dont know why it return whole html... please let me know if im missing anything...

Comment: add [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] attribute on top of ajaxTest method

Comment: im sorry, i already have that, i forgot to include here...

Comment: make the method static

Comment: The method is not static above hope, it is there in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code for your ajax, I think you forgot to mention the data-type in ajax :

```
 $("#testAjax").on("click", function () { 


var request = $.ajax({
        url: "Index.aspx/ajaxTest",
        method: "POST",
        type: "POST",
        data: { type_id : "Some dummy data" },
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            $('#loading').show();//show a loading image
        }
    });

        request.done(function( response ) {
             console.log(response);// you can view the object/html response in firefox firebug console
        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
 });
```

Your asp function should not return data but should print it like below :

```
[WebMethod]
public string ajaxTest()
{
    var test = "hello";

    print(test);//this is what I do to print in PHP, you should use ASP equivalent.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are accessing from code-behind the method should be static and must be marked as [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ajaxTest()
{
    var test = "hello";

    return test;
}
```

Comment: Could you try with type: 'GET' and see if you are getting the result?